# How to insert into the database booted in the test container in my junit testing code

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, functional-testing, testcontainers

I have the following code in the docker-compose.yml file to have a database started in my test container (the exposed port is dynamic).

```
 postgres:
    image: my-proxy.jfrog.io/postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: myTestingDB
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

Now, to have my functional testing done, I need to insert some records in the junit testing code before trigger the call. How should I do that?

Comment: Use the mechanisms you would normally use to interact with the database from within your Java/Spring application. You can also directly use Testcontainers (https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/), which provides helper functions that make this even easier for simple use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres offers a special location where scripts can be located in order to initialize the database. You can do the following:

```java
PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15.2-alpine")
   .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("init-db.sql"), "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/");
```

`init-db.sql` should be at `src/test/resources`

For more info read https://testcontainers.com/guides/configuration-of-services-running-in-container/#_initializing_the_container_by_copying_files_into_it